# Google container engine - update replication controller multi-container pods

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Trying to update a multi-container pods with

```
kubectl rolling-update my_rc --image=eu.gcr.io/project_id/myimage
```

I got:

```
error: Image update is not supported for multi-container pods
```

What is the way to update a single container or I must delete and recreate the pod ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, your best option is to update the yaml file defining the replication controller to use the new image and run:

```
kubectl rolling-update my_rc -f my_file.yaml
```

If you don't have a yaml file defining your replication controller, you can get one by running:

```
kubectl get rc my_rc --output=yaml > my_file.yaml
```

You should then be able to update the image specified in that file and run the rolling-update.

---

In the next release of Kubernetes (targeted for March), you'll be able to just pass the `--container` flag to tell kubectl which of the containers in the pod should use the new image:

```
kubectl rolling-update my_rc --container=my_container --image=eu.gcr.io/project_id/myimage
```

This feature was [added by a community member](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/17111) after version 1.1 was cut.

Comment: using kubectl rolling-update my_rc -f my_file.yaml with the same yaml file (which served to the creation) give me "error: monarch-redis-worker-master-controller-integration.yaml cannot have the same name as the existing Replica
tionController monarch" for me is not an update but a creation using an existing one, that's it ?

Comment: Ah, sorry for not including more detail originally. You'll also want to give the new RC a new name in order to differentiate it from the old one during the rollout (since they both exist in the same time as pods are moved from one to the other).